# @property not properly updating on object creation?

Tags: python, properties

I'm trying to dynamically add a database name into my connection info (which is a dictionary with key-mapped values for connection to, say, `psycopg2`).  For this I'm using a property.  How I imagine it working in my head is for it to take the information passed in to the object creator, and then dynamically set the `'database'` attribute in my `canvas_conn` dictionary to whatever `database_name` is passed in.  Then I've set an addition `@property` method for the `database_name` in case it ever gets changed to update the `canvas_conn`.  However, my unit test is failing with a `KeyError` for 'database'.

Here is my code:

```
class Shard(mu.PrettyStr):
    def __init__(self,
                 database_name,
                 schema_name,
                 cluster_id,
                 shard_id,
                 historical_connect=False,
                 canvas_conn=config3.CANVAS_INFO,
                 analytics_conn=config3.REDSHIFT_POSTGRES_INFO_PROD):
        """

        @type database_name: str
        :param server_id:
        @type schema_name: str
        :param name:
        @type cluster_id: str
        :param cluster_id:
        @type shard_id: str
        :param shard_id:
        @type historical_connect: bool
        :param historical_connect:
        @type canvas_conn: dict
        :param canvas_conn:
        @type analytics_conn: dict
        :param analytics_conn:
        """
        self._database_name = database_name
        self.schema_name = schema_name
        self.cluster_id = cluster_id
        self.shard_id = shard_id
        self.historical_connect = historical_connect
        self._canvas_conn = canvas_conn
        self.analytics_conn = analytics_conn

    @property
    def database_name(self):
        return self._database_name

    @database_name.setter
    def database_name(self, name):
        self._database_name = name
        # force the new database name into the conn info
        self._canvas_conn = self._canvas_conn

    @property
    def canvas_conn(self):
        return self._canvas_conn

    @canvas_conn.setter
    def canvas_conn(self, database_info):
        database_info['database'] = self._database_name
        self._canvas_conn = database_info
```

And here is my unit test:

```
def test_descriptor_correctly_sets_database_attribute(self):
        test_data = ('server_id', 'db_name', 'cluster_id', 'shard_id', True)
        test_shard = cu.Shard(*test_data)
        self.assertEqual(
            test_shard.canvas_conn['database'],
            test_shard.database_name
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are bypassing the property setter entirely:

```
self._canvas_conn = canvas_conn
```

That sets the `_canvas_conn` attribute directly, and the `@canvas_conn.setter` is not used at all.

Set `self.canvas_conn` instead:

```
self.canvas_conn = canvas_conn
```

because only then the setter is involved and `'database_name'` key is set too.

For the same reason, the following line in the `database` setter also is useless:

```
self._canvas_conn = self._canvas_conn
```